# How do you do client side routing when saving via methods?

Tags: meteor

I want to save some data and show it in a view template. So I want to do like the example below but using methods.

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post = {
      url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
      title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
    };

    post._id = Posts.insert(post);
    Router.go('postPage', post);
  }
});
```

I tried this:

```
'insertClubData': function(clubname, capacity, description, homepage){
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    var club = {
        clubname: clubname,
        description: description,
        capacity: parseInt(capacity),
        homepage: homepage,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        visitors: 0,
        occupancy: 0,
        trend: "club-1",
        createdBy: currentUserId
    }

    club._id = clubs.insert(club);
    Router.go('club', club);
},
```

but I get the error:

> Exception while invoking method '`insertClubData`' TypeError: Object
>   function router(req, res, next) { I20160425-14:04:55.724(2)?     //XXX
>
> this assumes no other routers on the parent stack which we should
>   probably fix

I understand that this is because `Router.go` is a client side method. But I also understand that you should avoid server side routing. So what's the most elegant solution?

This is my route:

```
Router.route('/club/:_id', {
    name: 'club',
    template: 'club',
    data: function(){
        return clubs.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about, you call the `method` from the client and in the callback on success you do the routing. For example:

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post = {
      url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
      title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
    };

    Meteor.call('insertPost', post, function(error, id) {
      if (error) {
        alert(error)
      } else {
        Router.go('postPage',  {_id: id});
      }
    });
  }
});
```

and on the server

```
Meteor.methods({
  insertPost: function(post) {
    // do checks
    id = Posts.insert(post);
    return id;
  }
});
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Almost. I have to change the routing to 
Router.go('club', {_id: id})
Otherwiase I get the error Exception in delivering result of invoking 'insertClubData': Error: Missing required parameters on path "/club/:_id". The missing params are: ["_id"]. The params object passed in was: "JgsK6ZRaqma8LM9uy".

Then it routes to the correct url for example 
http://localhost:3000/club/XdF4oQLdD7HuiHCY3
But it show Data not found?

Comment: I included my route in the question also.

Comment: That seems like a different problem, doesn't it? What happens if you point your browser directly to this address: localhost:3000/club/XdF4oQLdD7HuiHCY3 ?

Comment: Do you have a publication and subscription for the `club` data?

Comment: Yeah. That worked before. The strange thing is (I have a list with the clubs) If i click a link on the list it works just fine. But if I open the sam link in a new tab I get Data not found.

Yes. I have this publication
Meteor.publish('clubs', function(){
 return clubs.find();
});

And a templatesubscription
Template.club.onCreated(function () {
    this.subscribe('clubs');
});

Comment: As you said @tomsp. Different problem and I found it. I had this in my route file:

Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {
 // Shows notFound if a user enters url with missing id
 only: ['club', 'adminClub']
});

Don´t really see the problem, but it works when I remove that code.

Comment: The problem was that at the time the router tried to access the data, it wasn't there because the subscription was missing. You would need to add something along the lines of `waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe( 'clubs', this.params._id ); }` to make it work in the router.